# Security token in Salesforce.com

Tags: api, security, authentication, salesforce, token

I can't find security token with my account.. do I miss any Settings here ?

I have searched in google, and all of the information say that I need to go My Personal Information > Reset Security Token..
But I can't find that menu with my account.

The screenshot of my page on http://salesforce.com. http://prntscr.com/28l1on
There is no menu "My Personal Information" there..

Any suggestion will be so helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about salesforce accounts not programming. belongs on salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, but security token is needed because I want to do some development with salesforce.com :)

Answer (score 6):

It might be a few confused because salesforce has made some changes in their UI and for now on different instances might be different UI.

See screenshot For new UI which was released few month ago you 
[image]